# darcs appending extra directory separator

Tags: scp, darcs

I am having a problem using `darcs get`over ssh. I think the failure is because of something wrong in the path to the repository, but I cannot figure out how to correct.

The error message reads:

```
darcs failed:  Not a repository: britt@brittoffice.uwaterloo.ca:/home/britt/manuscripts/morient ((scp) failed to fetch: britt@brittoffice.uwaterloo.ca:/home/britt/manuscripts/morient//_darcs/inventory)
```

Note the two forward slashes after the repository name `morient`. I don't know where they come from or how to get rid of them. The directory path would be correct with only one. Is this darcs or scp or other?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like this issue was wrongly closed.  I reopened it. http://hub.darcs.net/simon/darcsden/issue/48